# Android location permissions reset after application upgrade

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-update-app

We had an android application implemeneted with location services. It asks the user for granting permission. Users given the permission and using the feature.

Recently we released an updated for the application. Our users are reporting that, the location permission popup re-appears for the approval. We could not understand what could be the reason for this. And we also do not find any documentation confirms that this is the expected behaviour.

Following are the application config details:

```
 minSdkVersion 24
 targetSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: If you have updated the target SDK version in your Android application, it might trigger the permission request again or there might be a bug in your application's code related to how it handles permission requests and checks for permission status.